# Getting a TypeError on semtorch learning model for image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I'm trying to train a deep learning model for image semantic segmentation and I'm using the code below to train my model. However, I am getting the below error on line 7. I have imported semtorch and fastai.

U-Net Model

```
transformPipeline=Compose([
                          Flip(p=0.5),
                          VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
                          Transpose(p=0.5),
                          Rotate(p=0.40,limit=10)
                          ],p=1)

transformPipeline=SegmentationAlbumentationsTransform(transformPipeline)


learn = get_segmentation_learner(dls=dls, number_classes=2, segmentation_type="Semantic Segmentation",
                                 architecture_name="unet", backbone_name="resnet34", 
                                 metrics=[segment_acc, no_bg_acc, Dice(), JaccardCoeff()],wd=1e-2,
                                 pretrained=True,normalize=True).to_fp16()


#learn.lr_find() # find learning rate
#learn.recorder # plot learning rate graph 


fname="unet-no-data-augmentation-before-unfreeze-WD-2-best"

callbacksFitBeforeUnfreeze = [
    ShowGraphCallback(),
    EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor=monitor_training,comp=comp_training, patience=patience),
    SaveModelCallback(monitor=monitor_training,comp=comp_training,every_epoch=False,fname=fname)  
]
#lr = 1e-03 # pick a lr
#learn.fit_one_cycle(10, slice(lr),cbs=callbacksFitBeforeUnfreeze, pct_start=0.3)


learn.load("unet-no-data-augmentation-before-unfreeze-WD-2-best")
learn.freeze()
learn.lr_find() # find learning rate
#learn.recorder # plot learning rate graph

#fname="unet-no-data-augmentation-after-unfreeze-WD-2-best"

callbacksFitAfterUnfreeze = [
    #ShowGraphCallback(),
    EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor=monitor_training,comp=comp_training, patience=patience),
    SaveModelCallback(monitor=monitor_training,comp=comp_training,every_epoch=False,fname=fname)  
]

learn.fit_one_cycle(1, slice(1e-7,1e-7),cbs=callbacksFitAfterUnfreeze)

learn.fine_tune(15,freeze_epochs=2)
learn.save('Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl') # save model
learn.load('Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl');

learn.export('Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl')

#*********this is the final trained model exported***********
!cp '/content/Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl' 'drive/My Drive/complete_refined_set/Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl'


path_img = 'dataset/test_set'
path_img


#*********this is the final trained model exported***********
!cp '/content/drive/My Drive/complete_refined_set/Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl' 'samples_png/model/Trained_ResNet34_Model.pkl'
```

I am getting the error:

---> 39         return super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)
40
41     @classmethod

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'limit'

Comment: What do you mean by `limit=10` in your rotate transform: `Rotate(p=0.40,limit=10)`?

Comment: ive kept the limit as a default value(10)

Comment: however, after removing the limit parameter completely, the error is Nonetype object is not iterable for the dataloader